# I cannot include my database to an .exe file

Tags: python, database, tkinter, sqlite, exe

I want to convert my .py files into an .exe file. To do this, I'm using auto-py-to-exe, but when I convert it, my database is not included. I can start my application, but when I'm on a window which need data from my database, it's not displayed.

```sh
pyinstaller -y -w --add-data "C:/Users/..../..../..../..../Base_SAV.db";"." 
...
"C:/..../..../..../..../..../MyCatSAV_Final.py"
```

My application works, as long as it doesn't need access to the database

Comment: I think you should tell us what database, and how your program accesses it, and any error message you get when it tries and fails. If you don't get an error message and it appears that the database is empty,  then it very likely is empty and your `.exe` is working with a different instance of it from the one you expect.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Using Data Files from a Module](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to include the database. `sqlite3` database is regular file which is created in your script current directory. There is no "standard place" for a `sqlite3` database.

Assuming you create your database like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("Base_SAV.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS(--------------)")
con.commit()
con.close()
```

and you compile it to `executable` you don't need to include the `database` you created in your working directory.As soon as you run the executable the database will be created in the folder which you have you `exe` file.

So `pyinstaller` command to convert it to executable should be:

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onfile    MyCatSAV_Final.py
```

which will work perfectly.

Comment: you can comment if you facing any challenges.

Answer (score -1):

I created a project and in this project my I created a seperate database.py file and refer my database.py to main.py like this

```
**con = sqlite3.connect(database=r'ims.db ')
cur = con.cursor()**
```

but after creating main.exe my database file is not working

Comment: Please don't ask questions on answers. If you encoutered a problem while following the solution provided on this question then leave a comment or create a new post (and link this one to the new post).